# How to convert a datetime to date in R, WITHOUT rounding the day?

Tags: r, date, datetime, time, data-conversion

I'm using R and trying to convert a datetime field into just the date? R gives me the desired format but keeps rounding up some of the day values. Specifically everything after 12 noon! I could not find any threads that address this exact problem. I actually figured out *a* solution but wanted to post the question because I spent a whole week troubleshooting.

```
#Convert the datetime field from character to a datetime
main_df$datetime <- strptime(main_df$ï..Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
main_df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(main_df$datetime, tz = Sys.timezone())
head(main_df$datetime)
class(main_df$datetime)

#Remove the poorly computer-titled character field that contained datetime info
main_df <- subset(main_df, select = -c(ï..Date))

#Use the NEW datetime field to create a date field
#main_df$Date <- trunc(main_df$datetime,"days")
main_df$Date <- as.Date(main_df$datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
?as.Date()
class(main_df$Date)

head(main_df$Date)
```

That returned:

```
head(main_df$datetime)
[1] "2020-05-16 00:31:00 CDT" "2020-05-16 00:30:00 CDT" "2020-05-15 23:33:00 CDT" "2020-05-15 15:33:00 CDT"
[5] "2020-05-15 22:31:00 CDT" "2020-05-15 22:12:00 CDT"
```

and

```
> class(main_df$Date)
[1] "Date"
> 
> head(main_df$Date)
[1] "2020-05-16" "2020-05-16" "2020-05-16" "2020-05-15" "2020-05-16" "2020-05-16"
```

Notice how the last 4 values for 'Date' should be 2020-05-**15** but instead, they are converted to be 2020-05-**16**. So what are some other ways to fix this? I'm going to post one way that worked but I doubt it's the cleanest.

Comment: `as.Date(trunc(main_df$datetime, 'days'))` should work

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your input dates include a timezone specification?  If not, they are ambiguous and the rounding may be right or it may be wrong.  If they do include a timezone specification, the `lubridate` package should handle them correctly.

I would advise against using `tz = Sys.timezone()` because that would make the interaction between input data and algorithm dependent on geography if your inputs don't include a timezone specification, so what works for you might not work for a different user in a different location.

Answer (score 2):

If we don't want to make use of the 'time', then use a regex to match a space followed by other characters (`" .*"`), replace with blank in `sub` and then convert to `Date` class.  The issue with converting to DateTime is that there are times `"23:33:00"` that would make it convert to next day

```
main_df$Date <- as.Date(sub(" .*", "", main_df$datetime), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that one as well. What worked for me was adding another "tz = Sys.timezone()" into the as.Date() function

Answer (score 1):

You could just extract date from datetime as a substring and convert it to Date type, using substr(x,begin,end) function, where x - your column, begin and end - begin and end of string to extract.

`main_df$Date <- as.Date(substr(main_df$datetime,1,10))`

I had the same issue and that function helped me to convert Datetime to Date without rounding.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question while doing some research on my own. So wanted to provide a bit more explanation for those who might come looking here.

The dates are getting rounded to the next day because **by default `as.Date` assumes you want to know the date in UTC**.

For example:

```
x <- as.POSIXct(c("2020-05-15 09:00:00", "2020-05-15 13:00:00", "2020-05-15 16:33:00", 
                  "2020-05-15 20:33:00", "2020-05-15 23:33:00", 
                  "2020-05-16 00:00:00", "2020-05-16 00:30:00"), tz = "America/Chicago")
x

as.Date(x)
# [1] "2020-05-15" "2020-05-15" "2020-05-15" "2020-05-16" "2020-05-16" "2020-05-16" "2020-05-16"
as.Date(x, tz = "America/Chicago")
# [1] "2020-05-15" "2020-05-15" "2020-05-15" "2020-05-15" "2020-05-15" "2020-05-16" "2020-05-16"
```

The rounding doesn't happen if correct timezone is specified to `as.Date` function.